# Mudras in Danda Pranam Namaskar

Tags: mudra

I've seen different hand and feet mudras in Staff Prostrations. This includes Sashtang Namaskar, and others with arms crossed (mimicking being bound) and feet crossed.

Does each mudra have a specific purpose, and if so: what purpose?